# I am trying to build emacs 24.5 with gtk+ 2.0

Tags: linux, emacs, build, gtk

while trying to build emacs 24.5 with gtk+ 2.0 I get the following error

```
checking whether GTK compiles... no
configure: error: Gtk+ wanted, but it does not compile, see config.log.  
Maybe some x11-devel files missing?
```

I am using the following command

```
./configure --prefix=/some_path/ --with-x-toolkit=gtk2 --enable-link-time-optimization
```

I have searched everywhere over the net but still not able to resolve this error

Comment: What does `config.log` say? Which Linux distribution are you using? Have you installed any of the GTK+ development packages?

Comment: Do you have GTK headers installed? On Debian-based systems, such as Ubuntu, the package would be named `libgtk2.0-dev` or so.

Comment: yes this was the problem I was not having the dev package, Its solved now :)

Comment: Why don't you use a more recent emacs?

Answer (score 1):

To build packages that require GTK+, you need to have development packages installed, which contain the header files needed for compilation.

On Debian-based systems, such as Ubuntu, the required package for GTK 2.x series would be named `libgtk2.0-dev`.